# c# Abstract Generic Class inheriting from Abstract Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to create an abstract generic class which inherits from another abstract generic class.

Here's what I have so far

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    public BaseClass(long id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : BaseClass where T : BaseClass {
    protected BaseClass(long id)
        : base(id) {

    }

    public static T Get(long id) {
        T item;
        return TryGet(id, out item) ? item : default(T);
    }

    public static bool TryGet(long id, out T item) {
        item = null; // This is where I call the cache but for this example I've removed so it will compile
        if (item != null) { return true; }
        else {
            // Call TryGetFallback method
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected abstract T TryGetFallback(long id);
}


public abstract class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass> {
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public DerivedClass(long id, String name)
        : base(id) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public class DerivedDerivedClass : DerivedClass {

    protected override DerivedDerivedClass TryGetFallback(long id) {
        // Handle the try get fallback
    }
}
```

The TryGetFallback method on the DerivedDerivedClass causes a compiler error.

Comment: DerivedDerivedClass inherits from DerivedClass<T> which inherits from DerivedClass which inherits from BaseClass. There's no BaseClass<T> in your chain and therefore, your method is not in the chain.

Comment: `BaseClass<T>` isn't used anywhere!

Comment: Also are you sure you want the type constraint for `BaseClass<T>` to be `BaseClass<T>`, seems a little... recursive!

Comment: Hi DavidG,

Yes I realised that but I can't work out how to get BaseClass<T> into the chain. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Right now `BaseClass<T>` is impossible to use due to the recursive type constraint. Fix that and then you can use it in the chain.

Comment: Recursive in that `BaseClass<T>` says that `T` has to be a `BaseClass<T>` which means that `T` is a `BaseClass<T>`.... and it's turtles all the way down!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to fix your `BaseClass<T>` implementation to not have a recursive type constraint.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> : BaseClass where T : new() {
    //snip
}
```

Then you can use it in your derived class, for example I will make it use `int` for the generic type parameter:

```
public abstract class DerivedClass : BaseClass<int> {
    //snip
}
```

And now if you compile it will warn you that `'DerivedDerivedClass' does not implement inherited abstract member 'BaseClass<int>.TryGetFallback(long)'`

Comment: Thanks DavidG, I'm getting a compiler error on:

'DerivedClass' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BaseClass<T>'

I do have an empty constructor in DerivedClass

Comment: Sounds like you are a little all over the place with your class hierarchy.

Comment: Did you by any chance make `DerivedClass` inherit from `BaseClass<DerivedClass>`? If so, don't do that.

Comment: If I don't make DerivedClass inherit from BaseClass<DerivedClass> then the base class method TryGetFallback isn't implement by the DerivedDerivedClass

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to do is have a TryGet method on my base class (I've not included in my code snippet) which tries to get the object from the cache and if it's not in the cache it calls the method TryGetFallback which I want to handle on the DerivedDerived class

Comment: In this case you could remove the `new` constraint from `BaseClass<T>`, but without seeing your real code I'm not sure if you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tips @DavidG it's helped me to solve the problem with the following code

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    public BaseClass(long id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : BaseClass where T : BaseClass<T>, new() {
    protected BaseClass(long id) : base(id) { }

    public static T Get(long id) {
        T item;
        return TryGet(id, out item) ? item : default(T);
    }

    public static bool TryGet(long id, out T item) {
        item = null; // Try to get item from cache here
        if (item != null) { return true; }
        else {
            T obj = new T();
            item = obj.TryGetFallback(id);
            return item != null;
        }
    }

    protected abstract T TryGetFallback(long id);
}

public abstract class DerivedClass<T> : BaseClass<T> where T : DerivedClass<T>, new() {
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public DerivedClass() : base(0) {  }

    public DerivedClass(long id, String name)
        : base(id) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    protected abstract override T TryGetFallback(long id);
}

public class DerivedDerivedClass : DerivedClass<DerivedDerivedClass> {

    public DerivedDerivedClass() {

    }

    protected override DerivedDerivedClass TryGetFallback(long id) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The pattern where you create a throw-away object `T obj = new T();` which is there only to let you call an instance method, it's a clear indication of a hack. The `TryGetFallback` method does not belong on `T`, it belongs on a related but separate class, which is often called a "factory" ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)).